# Getting "expected expression" error on a do while loop

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Get the plain text
    do
    {
        string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    }
    while (argc == 1);
    else 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }


}
```

Any reason I am getting an "expected expression" error on the "else" line? It says the expected expression is 
"else {" but even when I move the bracket to the same line as the else, it still gives me the error. Also my first time posting on stack and one of my first programs so please let me know if I need to post additional details about the issue.

Comment: An `else` must follow an `if`. Yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`else` cannot stand by itself. You need to have an `if` before the `else`. Apparently what you want is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Get the plain text
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    }
   else 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Even if your program had compiled it would have looped forever if `argc` was 1, since the value of `argc` would never have changed and the condition `while(argc == 1)` would have been true forever.

Answer (score 1):

"else" needs "if" statement preceding it somewhere in the code...
Example:
if{
 ... 
} 
else {
 ... 
}